# Picasso Images Reloading on Scroll in listview every time i scroll the list

Tags: android, listview, scroll, picasso

this is a listview loading images using picasso library .. each time i scroll up & down, it load images again and it make list very slow. I want to load images only one time and when i scroll the list found all images already loaded.

Comment: Maybe you can post your code as well so we don't have to imagine what you have there

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).